# PostgreSQL and huge arrays

Tags: postgresql

I have table where I store sample values (1 record per value).
Table get's huge (tens of millions of records).

I don't need to filter based on value, just quite frequently add new value and from time to time cleanup old values.

I was wondering about storing samples in one dimensional array instead (so 1 record per "sample type").

Does PG handles well such huge arrays?
Is adding new element with `array_append` will rewrite entire array or just add one element (IO concern)?

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, appending a single element to the array will "rewrite" the entire array (and thus replace the entire column contents). But "tens of millions of rows" is not considered "huge" nowadays.

Comment: I agree it should be not huge, but I have problem with clearing "old" records I just delete records older than 10 days and it takes forever.